# Класс, перечисление и ввод поля с клавиатуры

Tags: javascript

Создать  класс «Здание» (поля: адрес, количество этажей, год постройки, материал;  метод: Информация) и, на его основе, создать класс: «Офис» (поля:  владелец, цена за кв.метр; метод:  Стоимость аренды (количество кв.метров вводится с клавиатуры)). Поле «материал» должно быть представлено в виде перечисления.

```
<input class="m">
<script>
    let m=document.getElementsByClassName('m').value;
    class zdanie{
        constructor(adres, kol, year, mat){
            this.adres=adres;
            this.kol=kol;
            this.year=year;
            this.mat=mat;
        }
        getV(){
        document.write("Адрес: " + this.adres + "<br> Колличество этажей: " + this.kol + "<br> Год постройки: " + this.year + "<br> Материал:  " + this.mat)
    }
    }
    class oficc extends zdanie{
        constructor(vlad, price){
            this.vlad=vlad;
            this.price=price;
        }
        priceV(){
            let a = m*this.price;
        }
        getVV(){
        document.write("Владелец" + this.vlad + "Цена" + this.priceV())
    }
    }
    let z=new zdanie(121, 2, 2020, "kkk");
    z.getV();
    let o=new oficc("dsds",20);
    o.getVV();
</script>
```

Comment: А в чем вопрос то?

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так хотели?

```js
const Material = {
   STONE: "Камень",
   BRICK: "Кирпич",
   WOOD: "Дерево"
};

let m=document.getElementsByClassName('m').value;
class zdanie{
  constructor(adres, kol, year, mat){
      this.adres=adres;
      this.kol=kol;
      this.year=year;
      this.mat=mat;
  }
  getV(){
      document.write("Адрес: " + this.adres + "<br> Колличество этажей: " + this.kol + "<br> Год постройки: " + this.year + "<br> Материал:  " + this.mat)
  }
}

class oficc extends zdanie{
  constructor(adres, kol, year, mat, vlad, price){
      super(adres, kol, year, mat);
      this.vlad=vlad;
      this.price=price;            
  }
  priceV(){
      let a = m*this.price;
  }
  getVV(){
      document.write("<br> Владелец: " + this.vlad + "<br> Цена: " + this.priceV())
  } 
}

let z=new zdanie(121, 2, 2020, Material.BRICK);
z.getV();
let o=new oficc(121, 2, 2020, Material.BRICK, "dsds",20);
o.getVV();
```

```html
<input class="m">
```